# How to write a Windows Service that has a long running function using async?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

My first non-async attempt was to use a timer to call the process every 15 seconds. This quickly created multiple processes running which started a race condition on the database because the function `_myApp.ProcessQueue();` could take 5-10 minutes to run based on the size of the queue. This actually locked up the database because it was trying to read and write to the same rows. If I increase the timer it would prevent the potential for a race condition but I don't think that's a very pragmatic way to go about this service.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    _log.Info($"Service is started at {DateTime.Now}.");
    timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
    timer.Interval = 15000;
    timer.Enabled = true;
}

private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    int recCount = _dbHandler.CheckQueueCount();

    if (recCount > 0)
    {
        _log.Info($"Found {recCount} records in the queue.");

        try
        {
            _myApp.ProcessQueue();
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _log.Error(exception);                    
            Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm thinking the way to go about this is to use an asynchronous function but I'm having trouble getting that written since I haven't used .Net's async capabilities before.

Comment: I suggest you to evaluate https://www.hangfire.io/

Comment: Nice! This looks really promising. Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: Definitely look at TopShelf if you are going the Windows Service route. It takes care of registration/unregistration, hooks into lots of DI containers, logging frameworks, etc.

Comment: We have an old but functioning custom task manager that watches windows services and alerts if they stop. It's not super robust but it functions. I'm going to talk to the team about transitioning to using an off the shelf product like TopShelf or Hangfire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `OnStart()` to initialize your runner in an other thread (`Task.Run()` or if you have to tune some parameters `Task.Factory.Start()`) to have a proper return of the method within short time.

If I understand you correctly, you only want to process one job at a time and after that you want to process the next one, right?

My examples include always to wait for additional 15s. If you don't want this, you have to adjust the code a little bit.

**Without async/await**

To synchronize your loop with your job processing, you can start the job in another thread (see above) and use a `AutoResetEvent`. In your loop you gonna wait with `_autoResetEvent.WaitOne()` and as soon as your job has been done you can signal with `_autoResetEvent.Set()` the other thread to continue.

Use something appropriate to wait for the 15s like `Thread.Sleep()`

**With async/await** 
It's much easier, you only have to await your task call.

```
await Task.Run(() => MyJobMethod(argA, argB, ...));
await Task.Delay(15000);
```